# json formatting - remove hyperlink in one view only

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

Hi I have two views in a SharePoint Online document library.
I want to strike-out and disable the hyperlink of column 'Name' if Retracted column is true. I've carried this out using 'Format columns' but it affects all the views.
I understand it is possible to utilise 'additionalRowClass' so it affects a single view, but cannot find a way to target Title column. Is it possible or a workaround to achieve.

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": {
    "operator": ":",
    "operands": [
      {
        "operator": "==",
        "operands": [
          "[$Retracted]",
          true
        ]
      },
      "sp-css-backgroundColor-BgCoral sp-field-fontSizeSmall sp-css-color-CoralFont" ,
      ""
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: When you apply column formatting, it is applied at column level and not individual view level. Hence all the views will have same formatting for Name column. Can you explain what you are trying to do using view formatting with this: *but cannot find a way to target Title column*?

Comment: I want to strike-out and disable the hyperlink of column 'Name' if Retracted column is true on a single view.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to achieve it using `additionalRowClass` and view formatting as it only takes the CSS class as input and the CSS class to disable all elements in the list view might not be available in Microsoft supported CSS.